# Zoom in and out in widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I make a zoom effect with key input on a widget? The widget is inside a scroll area and there are some drawings made with QPainter who change with user input. The zoom would affect the length of the scrolling bar, the closer you are, the smaller the bar becomes. The zoom at minimum level should make the scroll bar as big as the widget area, so all the content in the widget could be visualized.

MRE:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QColor
import sys


class Diedrico(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt.black), 5))
        qp.drawRect(500, 500, 1000, 1000)


class UiVentana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiVentana, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(520, 520)
        self.widget_central = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        scrol = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget_central)
        scrol.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scrol.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 500, 500))
        scrol.setWidgetResizable(False)

        contenido = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        contenido.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000))
        scrol.setWidget(contenido)

        self.Diedrico = Diedrico(contenido)
        self.Diedrico.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget_central)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UiVentana()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have done it @S.Nick

Comment: You may have a look at this -- https://github.com/danboid/shufti

Comment: @mishsx that is quite interesting, but can I use that program inside a widget?

Comment: Could you explain more and illustrate what is it you want? That may help get more attention.

Comment: @Pavel.D Done, but I have not found any illustrative example of what I want

Comment: @PepeElMago33. Well, you see you get answer as soon as you put more word on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you want to *reinvent the wheel*? Instead of wanting to implement the logic of the scaling feature, use the classes that already do it. In this case, a good option is to use QGraphicsView with QGraphicsScene:

Note: The shortcut standard Zoom In and Zoom Out are associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, respectively.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Diedrico(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black), 5)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawRect(500, 500, 1000, 1000)


class UiVentana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    factor = 1.5

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiVentana, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self._scene)

        self._diedrico = Diedrico()
        self._diedrico.setFixedSize(2000, 2000)
        self._scene.addWidget(self._diedrico)

        self.setCentralWidget(self._view)

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.ZoomIn),
            self._view,
            context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
            activated=self.zoom_in,
        )

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.ZoomOut),
            self._view,
            context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
            activated=self.zoom_out,
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def zoom_in(self):
        scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
        scale_tr.scale(UiVentana.factor, UiVentana.factor)

        tr = self._view.transform() * scale_tr
        self._view.setTransform(tr)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def zoom_out(self):
        scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
        scale_tr.scale(UiVentana.factor, UiVentana.factor)

        scale_inverted, invertible = scale_tr.inverted()

        if invertible:
            tr = self._view.transform() * scale_inverted
            self._view.setTransform(tr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UiVentana()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to use <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> for ZoomIn and ZoomOut, respectively, then just change the shortcuts to:

```py
QtWidgets.QShortcut(
    QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Plus), # <---
    self._view,
    context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
    activated=self.zoom_in,
)

QtWidgets.QShortcut(
    QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Minus), # <---
    self._view,
    context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
    activated=self.zoom_out,
)
```

Comment: Which keys are used to zoom in and out?

Comment: @PepeElMago33 Use Ctrl++ and Ctrl+-

Comment: Can they be redefined?

Comment: @PepeElMago33 Yes, what shortcuts do you want to change?

Comment: For example using the key + instead of ctrl + +

Comment: @PepeElMago33 I don't understand you What is the key/shortcut for zoomIn? and What is the key/shortcut for ZoomOut?

Comment: In that example the shortcut for zoomIn is control + +, I would like to change the key combination to the + key, for example

Comment: Now I need to add a reset feature who centers the camera and sets the zoom to the initial state

Comment: @PepeElMago33 If you want to reset the zoom then use: `self._view.setTransform(QtGui.QTransform())`

Comment: Im trying to move the initial position of the scroll bar with:
```python
self._view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self._scene)
self._view.verticalScrollBar().setValue(500)
self._view.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(500)
```
but it does not work

Comment: @PepeElMago33 When you say something in OS don't just say "it doesn't work", you must explain in detail what you get and what you want to get. On the other hand, your question merits a new post since the comments are made to discuss the initial question (the zoom) and not on other topics so I invite you to create a new post.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the answer. But there is a problem and that is why `setFiixedSize` doesn't accept values bigger than something like 23000 for width and height? >>  `self._diedrico.setFixedSize(24000, 24000)`  
Are there any limits?

Comment: @just_learning Exactly: The objective of this section is to discuss the answer, if instead your question is not about it then create a new question, that is the logic of having an organized site.